# Clear old/invalid DNS cache in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I am calling a remote https url using python `requests` inside aws lambda in python, which fails with:

`Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

But I know the DNS for https url is fine because I can access the URL from all other environments outside AWS Lambda, including my local machine. It even works fine from an EC2 instance running inside the same VPC.

I believe the DNS settings were recently changed/fixed but it seems like the old values may be cached somewhere so the lambda function is using the old broken DNS.

Is there a way to clear this?

I already forced the Lambda functions to be restated (by changing the memory allocation) so I am confident is is not actually cached inside the lambda function - it must be cleared at a different level, such as inside the VPC/Subnet/etc?

Comment: The lambda function was able to connect to the URL previously?

Comment: So your lambda is in a VPC? How did you ensure internet access for your function from the VPC?

Comment: It is _possible_ that old DNS values are living in a cache, especially if the previous record had a very long TTL. But I would start by verifying that I'm connecting to what I think I am.